# How to remove XCode 4.2 and install 4.1 to develop Ruby / Rails on OSX Lion?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode, rvm, osx-lion

I develop Rails apps using RVM (ruby version manager).

I had to download XCode, in the app store I got only version 4.2.

Now RVM says that it can't build rubies properly with this XCode, so I followed this tutorial:

http://www.frederico-araujo.com/2011/07/30/installing-rails-on-os-x-lion-with-homebrew-rvm-and-mysql/

I downloaded the XCode version from the link that is shown when you type `rvm requirements` in the console. (https://developer.apple.com/downloads/download.action?path=Developer_Tools/xcode_4.1_for_lion/xcode_4.1_for_lion.dmg)

Now, there is a 3.09 GB .dmg with an installXCodeLion package, and it installs successfully, but after there is no XCode or whatsoever on my system. (I stopped also the iTunesHelper process... )

Anybody knows how to install XCode 4.1 ? Or where to officially get it from Apple?
Or anybody uses RVM and ruby 1.9.2 w/ Rail 3.1 successfully on Lion?

Comment: you can use https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer which will provide gcc-4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll save you any additional trouble: Your rvm installation is out of date.

Reinstall Xcode 4.2, grab the latest rvm, and get back to your work with no fuss and no hoop-jumping.

Comment: well, my RVM was a fresh installation, just after installing it the readme in the console said that it won't work properly with XCode 4.2 - so I did not even try it. But now I tried installing rubies through RVM with 4.2 and everything works fine. So i would say the readme from RVM is out of date... thanks anyway

Comment: Most things will work, but some won't. Definitely seeing crashes left and right with gems that are using native libraries.

Comment: @colinm: it is not issue with rvm, any ruby older from 1.9.3-p0 is not supposed to be supported fully on llvm compiler(Xcode 4.2 has only llvm gcc), also there are gems with native extensions that do not compile on llvm, there are other ways to get gcc-4.2 Xcode 4.1 is not required, you can use osx gcc installer

Answer (score 7):

Uninstall 4.2 with

`/Library/Developer/4.2/uninstall-devtools --mode=all`

Then XCode 4.1 Download is [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/download.action?path=Developer_Tools/xcode_4.1_for_lion/xcode_4.1_for_lion.dmg)

Answer (score 5):

thanks a lot
it is helpful

first:

Uninstall 4.2 with

/Library/Developer/4.2/uninstall-devtools --mode=all

secondly:

download xcode4.1 installed dmg file

run dmg file to install Xcode

be sure there is no "install Xcode" file in your "/application" directory

after running dmg file , one new "install Xcode" file will be created in "application" directory.

finally:
run install Xcode to finish installation

Comment: Thanks--final step here is easy to miss, the dmg doesn't instruct you to do anything when it is finished.

Comment: make sure that there are no other "Install Xcode" in the applications folder. I had renamed my 4.2 install to "Install Xcode 4.2" and it wasn't until I deleted it did the Install Xcode for 4.1 show up.

Answer (score 4):

Dont you have an "Install Xcode" application on your Applications folder ? I had to run it to complete the installation after executing the package from the xcode_4.1_for_lion.dmg

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve Xcode 4.1, you have to log in to the [Mac Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/index.action) and go to [Additional Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action). You will find all the installation disk images for all the Xcode versions.

Comment: thanks. but that is actually exactly the file 'rvm requirements' linked to. The one where nothing happened after installation. Will download again and see if anything changes..

Comment: Have you uninstalled the Xcode installation by running "sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all" ? After that, you have to restart the machine before installing Xcode 4.1.

Comment: i actually 'uninstalled' Xcode just by typing 'sudo rm -rf /Developer' to the console, as mentioned in the linked tutorial. ouch.

Comment: well maybe i will just reinstall 4.2 as I still have the installer app from the appstore, then uninstall correctly and then try again with the fresh downloaded 4.1

Comment: It still does not work :( - I reinstalled 4.2, uninstalled it correcty, tried the fresh downloaded xcode_4.1_lion restarted before, between after... still no "Developer" folder or any sign of XCode.... argh!

Answer (score 2):

Guillaume Petit is correct - delete Install Xcode from the APplications folder first (the 4.2 version from the App Store).

Run the xcode_4.1_for_lion.dmg again and it will create a new Install Xcode in Applications (which is the 4.1 version).  Run that and Developer Tools will be installed as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if anyone is aware, but I read in another post that you have to use clang option to install rubies. example:

```
rvm install 1.9.2 --with-gcc=clang
```

Answer (score 0):

The developer tools install in the "Developer" folder on your system disk.
(not in the "Applications" folder!)

The old XCode releases can indeed be found on the Mac Dev Center download site.

Comment: yeah i know, but the Developer folder is not created, also it says "installation successful"