# How do I install Ruby 1.9.3 with RVM?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I am attempting to install Ruby with RVM. I already have Ruby installed, but I have now installed RVM and am trying to install Ruby 1.9.3 using `rvm 1.9.3` and I get the following error:

```
 Error running ' ./configure --prefix=/Users/anderskitson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0 --
enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml --with-opt-dir=/Users/anderskitson/.rvm/usr ', please read /Users/anderskitson/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p0/configure.log
    There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

Comment: Did you look in the log it tells you to look in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rvm 1.9.3` will not install Ruby. It will tell RVM to switch to using Ruby 1.9.3 after it has been installed. Did you mean `rvm install 1.9.3`?

Have you installed all the dependencies? Try `rvm requirements`.

Check the output of `rvm info`, and make sure everything looks sane.

---

To uninstall XCode: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7960899/128421

Comment: rvm requirements it's telling me to either downgrade to Xcode 4.1 on unistall Xcode and install osx-gcc-installer which I assume i can get from git-hub

Comment: @AndersKitson, see the added link in my answer.

Comment: I just installed the osx-gcc-installed from github and it works now